# sqlsrv find maximum from the table

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Previously I was using the MySQL. With that I was able to use the query below to get the maximum number from the database.

Here 'No' is the varchar(10):

```
SELECT max(cast(No as unsigned)) as No FROM `tableName` LIMIT 1
```

The above query working fine in MySQL. I want to do the same thing in the MS SQL. When I run the same query, I get the following error:

```
Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

Any advice on this?

Comment: Is that the whole query? If not, please can you post the whole query?

Comment: I don't think SQL/Server supports unsigned (so it probably thinks it's a parameter) - try int and see what happens.

Comment: @PeterJ - absolutely right: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx

Comment: PeterJ, would you mind posting that as an answer? Good spot.

Answer (score 1):

There is no LIMIT in SQL Server, no unsigned datatype,  and no need to quote the table name.
Does this work:

```
SELECT max(cast(No as bigint)) as No FROM tableName
```